# Angular ng-view not working with express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular-routing

I'm trying work open page home of directory partials/home using `ng-view` and `ng-view` not working with express. A new page opens with render when acess http://localhost:3000/home. All routes defined for angular has no effect. I would like to know how to render my page **partials/home.html** in **index.html** using ng-view with express.

app.js

```
//módulos
var express = require('express');
var load = require('express-load');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');


//uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

load('routes').then('controllers').into(app);

server.listen(3000);
console.log('Site no ar ...');

module.exports = app;
```

Routes Express - index.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/:name', function(req, res){
    var name = req.params.name;
    res.render('partials/' + name);
});

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

};
```

Routes Angular - Location: public/app/app.js

```
var app = angular.module('appSiteFio',['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

// remove o # da url
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'index.html',
        controller  : 'mainController',
    })


    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
        controller  : 'homeController',
    })


    .otherwise ({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

Comment: Hi! Did you solve this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing the index.js file to something like:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
app.use(express.static('/partials')); //here you can write your partials directory. 
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

};
```

(Also change your templateUrl inside angular file with the partials prefix.);

that way angular will allways will be loaded and angular router will deal with all the views fetching from the static partials folder

Comment: The home page is still open in a new tab. The ng-view has not effect.